# C program to read datas from an antenna connected with USB

Tags: c, windows, usb, telecommunication

i'm trying to write a C program to read datas from an antenna connected with USB. I never did something like this and i'm totally confused. I'm using Windows SO, but i don't know how to access to the device and how to read datas. Can you help me? There are specific functions to do that?

Comment: what type of antenna? how is it connected via USB? Can you give more specifics, make, model? What type of data are you trying to read? Is it a RTL dongle?

Comment: Onestly i still don't know the model of antenna that i will have to work with, but i know it is connected as a seriale and that it uses MavLink protocol (they are telemetric datas). Sorry i can't give much informations but is everything I know

Comment: maybe here http://qgroundcontrol.org/mavlink/start

Comment: My problem is how to read these datas, i don't know how enter into the device

Comment: The link to the mavlink page has tutorials and api guides - have you worked through these first? Maybe once you've had a go at starting to code something using the api you might have some more specific questions? If you're looking for examples of code already using their api, have you looked online elsewhere for any example code, other people using the api, or whether there's a support or user group for mavlink users? Quick reminder for ontopic questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic